# Menu with line-height makes menu dissappear on zoom

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a fixed header with a menu floated on the right (http://outletdokkum.nl/nofcom/)

This menu uses Line-height to vertically center in the header bar. It's working great but there's one problem. I'm working on the responsive styles now and when I zoom to a certain point the menu dissapaears and I can't find it on the page.

I think it's a problem with the line-height but I'm not sure. I use Jquery to scale when scrolling down.

Html:

```
<header id="header_nav">
    <div id="header-wrap">
        <section id="branding">
            <a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="http://outletdokkum.nl/nofcom/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/logo-transparent.png" class="brand-img" alt="logo-nofcom"/></a>
        </section>

        <nav id="menu" role="navigation">   
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav>
    </div>

</header>
```

CSS:

```
#header_nav {
width:100%;
height:120px;
background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index: 9999;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
overflow: hidden;
line-height: 120px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #cccccc;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #cccccc;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #cccccc;
}

#header-wrap{
width: auto;
max-width: 1060px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#branding{
width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.brand-img{
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
width: auto;
height: 120px;
max-height: 120px;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu{
width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 18px;
color: #444444;
z-index:9999;
}

#menu ul{
float: right;
}

#menu ul li{
float: left;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#menu ul li a{
color: #444444;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
color: #000000;
cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li.current_page_item{
font-weight: 700;
color: #000000;
}
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 100)
    {
        if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
        {
            $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                "height":"80px",
                "line-height":"80px"
            },300);

        /*
            $('#slider').data('size','big');
            $('#slider').stop().animate({
                marginTop:'80px'
            },300);
        */

        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
        {
            $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                "height":"120px",
                "line-height":"120px"
            },300);

        /*
            $('#slider').data('size','big');
            $('#slider').stop().animate({
                marginTop:'120px'
            },300);
        */
        }  
    }
});

$(function(){
    $('.brand-img').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 100)
    {
        if($('.brand-img').data('size') == 'big')
        {
            $('.brand-img').data('size','small');
            $('.brand-img').stop().animate({
                height:'80px'
            },300);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($('.brand-img').data('size') == 'small')
        {
            $('.brand-img').data('size','big');
            $('.brand-img').stop().animate({
                height:'120px'
            },300);
        }  
    }
});
</script>
```

I hope it's clear what I mean. Try resizing your browser windows to see the colors change to blue/green/red (responsive) The menu is gone from the blue part.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the width of your menu `ul` + the width of your logo is exceeding the available space, because both are floated, the menu then wraps below the logo to the next line- which is hidden from view. To prevent this you either need to define the `width` and/or `min-width` of the total header area, or define how to handle the menu when the screen reduces to sizes it cannot all be shown at.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 640px){
 /* e.g. add behaviour to reduce the width of your menu */
}
```

Comment: I already use media queries, but I think it's strange that the menu dissappears. I will do a trail and error with the media queries and the menu. Will come back to this in a couple of minutes.